# How to create Unicode parameter and variable names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameter, unicode

All of this works:

```
CREATE DATABASE [¯\_(ツ)_/¯];
GO
USE [¯\_(ツ)_/¯];
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [¯\_(ツ)_/¯];
GO
CREATE TABLE [¯\_(ツ)_/¯].[¯\_(ツ)_/¯]([¯\_(ツ)_/¯] NVARCHAR(20));
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [¯\_(ツ)_/¯] ON [¯\_(ツ)_/¯].[¯\_(ツ)_/¯]([¯\_(ツ)_/¯]);
GO
INSERT INTO [¯\_(ツ)_/¯].[¯\_(ツ)_/¯]([¯\_(ツ)_/¯]) VALUES (N'[¯\_(ツ)_/¯]');
GO
CREATE VIEW [¯\_(ツ)_/¯].[vw_¯\_(ツ)_/¯] AS SELECT [¯\_(ツ)_/¯] FROM [¯\_(ツ)_/¯].[¯\_(ツ)_/¯];
GO
CREATE PROC [¯\_(ツ)_/¯].[sp_¯\_(ツ)_/¯] @Shrug NVARCHAR(20) AS SELECT [¯\_(ツ)_/¯] FROM [¯\_(ツ)_/¯].[vw_¯\_(ツ)_/¯] WHERE [¯\_(ツ)_/¯] = @Shrug;
GO
EXEC [¯\_(ツ)_/¯].[¯\_(ツ)_/¯].[sp_¯\_(ツ)_/¯] @Shrug = N'[¯\_(ツ)_/¯]';
GO
```

But you can probably see where I'm going with this: I don't want @Shrug, I want `@¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.

Neither of these work on any version from 2008-2017:

```
CREATE PROC [¯\_(ツ)_/¯].[sp_¯\_(ツ)_/¯] @[¯\_(ツ)_/¯] NVARCHAR(20) AS SELECT [¯\_(ツ)_/¯] FROM [¯\_(ツ)_/¯].[vw_¯\_(ツ)_/¯] WHERE [¯\_(ツ)_/¯] = @[¯\_(ツ)_/¯];
GO
CREATE PROC [¯\_(ツ)_/¯].[sp_¯\_(ツ)_/¯] [@¯\_(ツ)_/¯] NVARCHAR(20) AS SELECT [¯\_(ツ)_/¯] FROM [¯\_(ツ)_/¯].[vw_¯\_(ツ)_/¯] WHERE [¯\_(ツ)_/¯] = [@¯\_(ツ)_/¯];
GO
```

So, is there a way to use unicode stored procedure parameter names?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Well, identifiers are always Unicode / `NVARCHAR`, so technically you can't create anything that doesn't have a Unicode name 🙃.

The problem you are having here is due entirely to the classification of the character(s) being used. The rules for *regular* (i.e. non-delimited) identifiers are:

- First letter must be:

  - A letter as defined by the Unicode Standard 3.2.
  - underscore (_), at sign (@), or number sign (#)
- Subsequent letters can be:

  - **Letters as defined in the Unicode Standard 3.2.**
  - **Decimal numbers from either Basic Latin or other national scripts.**
  - **underscore (_), at sign (@), number sign (#), or dollar sign ($)**
- **Embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed.**
- **Supplementary characters are not allowed.**

I bolded the only rules that matter in this context. The reason that the "First letter" rules are not relevant here is that the first letter in all local variables and parameters is always the "at sign" `@`.

And to be clear: what is considered a "letter" and what is considered a "decimal digit" is based upon the [properties](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/properties.jsp) that each character is assigned in the Unicode Character Database. Unicode assigns many properties to each character, such as: is_uppercase, is_lowercase, is_digit, is_decimal, is_combining, etc, etc. This is not a matter of what we mortals would consider letters or decimal digits, but which characters have been assigned these properties. These properties are often used in Regular Expressions to match on "punctuation", etc. For example, `\p{Lu}` matches any upper-case letter (across all languages / scripts), and `\p{IsDingbats}` matches any "Dingbats" character.

So, in your attempt to do:

```
DECLARE @¯\_(ツ)_/¯ INT;
```

only the `_` (underscore or "low line") and `ツ` (Katakana Letter Tu U+30C4) characters fit into those rules. Now, all of the characters in `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` are fine for delimited identifiers, but unfortunately it seems that variable / parameter names and `GOTO` labels cannot be delimited (although cursor names can be).

So, for variable / parameter names, since they cannot be delimited, you are stuck with using only characters that qualify as being either "letters" or "decimal digits" as of Unicode 3.2 (well, according to the documentation; I need to test if classifications have been updated for newer versions of Unicode since classifications are handled differently than sort weights).

**HOWEVER #1**, things are not as straight-forward as they should be. I have now been able to complete my research and have found that the stated definition is not entirely correct. The precise (and verifiable) definition of which characters are valid for regular identifiers is:

- First character:

  - Can be anything classified *in Unicode 3.2* as "ID_Start" (which does include "Letters" but also "letterlike numeric characters")
  - Can be `_` (low line / underscore) or `＿` (fullwidth low line)
  - Can be `@`, but *only* for variables / parameters
  - Can be `#`, but if schema-bound object, then only for Tables and Stored Procedures (in which case they indicate that the object is temporary)
- Subsequent characters:

  - Can be anything classified *in Unicode 3.2* as "ID_Continue" (which includes "decimal" numbers, but also "spacing and nonspacing combining marks", and "connecting punctuation marks")
  - Can be `@`, `#`, or `$`
  - Can be any of the 26 characters classified *in Unicode 3.2* as format control characters

(fun fact: the "ID" in "ID_Start" and "ID_Continue" stands for "Identifier". Imagine that ;-)

According to "Unicode Utilities: UnicodeSet":

- Valid starting characters

  [[:Age=3.2:] & [:ID_Start=Yes:]](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%3AAge%3D3.2%3A%5D+%26+%5B%3AID_Start%3DYes%3A%5D)

  ```
  -- Test one "Letter" from each of 10+ languages, as of Unicode 3.2
  DECLARE @ᔠᑥᑒᏯשፙᇏᆇᄳᄈლဪඤaൌgೋӁｳﺲﶨ   INT;
  -- works


  -- Test a Supplementary Character that is a "Letter" as of Unicode 3.2
  DECLARE @ INT;-- Mathematical Script Capital W (U+1D4B2)
  /*
  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line XXXXX
  Incorrect syntax near '0xd835'.
  */
  ```
- Valid continuation characters

  [[:Age=3.2:] & [:ID_Continue=Yes:]](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%3AAge%3D3.2%3A%5D%20%26%20%5B%3ANumeric_Type%3DDecimal%3A%5D)

  ```
  -- Test various decimal numbers, but none are Supplementary Characters
  DECLARE @६৮༦൯௫୫９ INT;
  -- works (including some Hebrew and Arabic, which are right-to-left languages)


  -- Test a Supplementary Character that is a "decimal" number as of Unicode 3.2
  DECLARE @ INT; -- MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK DIGIT FOUR (U+1D7DC)
  /*
  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line XXXXX
  Incorrect syntax near '0xd835'.
  */
  -- D835 is the first character in the surrogate pair D835 DFDC that makes up U+1D7DC
  ```

**HOWEVER #2**, not even searching the Unicode database can be that easy. Those two searches do produce a list of valid characters for those categorizations, and those characters are from Unicode 3.2, BUT the definitions of the various categorizations changes across versions of the Unicode Standard. Meaning, the definition of "ID_Start" in Unicode v 10.0 (what that search is using today, 2018-03-26) is *not* what it was in Unicode v 3.2. So, the online search cannot provide an exact list. But you can grab the Unicode 3.2 data files and grab the list of "ID_Start" and "ID_Continue" characters from there to compare to what SQL Server actually uses. And I have done this and confirmed an exact match to the rules I stated above in "HOWEVER #1".

The following two blog posts detail the steps taken to find the exact list of characters, including links to the import scripts:

1. [The Uni-Code: The Search for the True List of Valid Characters for T-SQL Regular Identifiers, Part 1](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/04/02/the-uni-code-the-search-for-the-true-list-of-valid-characters-for-t-sql-regular-identifiers-part-1/)
2. [The Uni-Code: The Search for the True List of Valid Characters for T-SQL Regular Identifiers, Part 2](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/04/04/the-uni-code-the-search-for-the-true-list-of-valid-characters-for-t-sql-regular-identifiers-part-2/)

Finally, for anyone that just wants to see the list and is not concerned with what it took to discover and verify it, you can find that here:

[Completely Complete List of Valid T-SQL Identifier Characters](https://sqlquantumleap.com/reference/completely-complete-list-of-valid-t-sql-identifier-characters)
(please give the page a moment to load; it's 3.5 MB and almost 47k lines)

---

Regarding "valid" ASCII characters, such as `/` and `-`, not working: the issue has nothing to do with whether or not the characters are also defined in the ASCII character set. In order to be valid, the character has to have either the `ID_Start` or `ID_Continue` property, or be one of the few custom characters noted separately. There are quite a few "valid" ASCII characters (62 of the 128 total — mostly punctuation and control characters) that are not valid in "Regular" Identifiers.

Regarding Supplementary Characters: while they certainly can be used in *delimited* identifiers (and the documentation does not appear to be stating otherwise), if it is true that they cannot be used in regular identifiers, that is most likely due to them not being fully supported in built-in functions prior to Supplementary Character-Aware Collations were introduced in SQL Server 2012 (they are treated as two individual "unknown" characters), nor could they even be differentiated from each other in non-binary Collations prior to the 100-level Collations (introduced in SQL Server 2008).

Regarding ASCII: 8-bit encodings are not being used here since all identifiers are Unicode / `NVARCHAR` / UTF-16 LE. The statement `SELECT ASCII('ツ');` returns a value of `63` which is a "?" (try: `SELECT CHAR(63);` ) since that character, even if prefixed with an upper-case "N", is certainly not in Code Page 1252. However, that character is in the Korean Code Page and it produces the correct result, even without the "N" prefix, in a Database with a Korean default Collation:

```
SELECT UNICODE('ツ'); -- 12484
```

Regarding the first letter affecting the outcome: this is not possible since the first letter for local variables and parameters is always `@`. The first letter that we get to control for these names is actually the 2nd character of the name.

Regarding why local variable names, parameter names, and `GOTO` labels cannot be delimited: I suspect this is due to these items being a part of the language itself and not something that will find its way into a system table as data.

Comment: So awesome, thanks. That led me to this, which is going to make for a great blog post: https://gist.github.com/BrentOzar/9b08b5ab2b617847dbe4aa0297b4cd5b

Comment: @BrentOzar have you had a CT scan recently?

Comment: Wow, that’s quite an impressive answer! And I second Ross Presser’s remark.

Answer (score 22):

I don't think it's Unicode that's causing the problem; in the case of local variable or parameter names, it's that the character isn't a valid ASCII/Unicode 3.2 character (and there isn't any escaping sequence for variables/parameters like there are for other entity types).

This batch works fine, it uses a Unicode character that simply doesn't violate the rules for non-delimited identifiers:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[]
  @ツ int
AS
  CREATE TABLE [#ツ] (ツ int);
  INSERT [#ツ](ツ) SELECT @ツ;
  SELECT ツ+1 FROM [#ツ];
GO
EXEC dbo.[] @ツ = 1;
```

As soon as you try to use a slash or a dash, both of which are valid ASCII characters, it bombs:

> `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure 
>   Incorrect syntax near '-'.`

The documentation does not address why *these* identifiers are subject to slightly different rules than all other identifiers, or why they can't be escaped like the others.

Comment: Hi Aaron. Just to clarify some points here: 1) the first character isn't an issue since the first character is actually the `@` of the var / param name. Any of the characters that aren't working shouldn't work in any position, even if preceded by valid characters. 2) the doc states only that supplementary characters can't be used in regular identifiers (which does seem to be the case for all that I've tried), but places no restrictions on delimited identifiers, just like with embedded spaces. Also, I believe these are different because they are part of the T-SQL language, not things in the DB.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I feel like the problem is simply and entirely that a parameter name can't be delimited like other entities. If I could wrap square brackets or double quotes around a parameter name, I could put any of these characters into it, in any position. The question postulates that you can't use Unicode characters in a parameter name, and that is clearly not the case. There are some Unicode characters you **can** use, and some ASCII characters you **can't**.

Comment: Yes, I agree that if variable / parameter names and `GOTO` labels allowed for being delimited, then the only restriction would be the length. I can only assume that parsing and/or handling those few items happens at a different level or has some other constraints that made allowing for delimited values unworkable. At least I hope that it wasn't arbitrary or an oversight.

Comment: (hadn't seen the update to your comment when I replied a moment ago). Yes, the question does imply that the O.P. is unable to use Unicode characters, but the phrasing of the question is technically incorrect as all names are always Unicode / NVARCHAR. This has nothing to do with ASCII since that's an 8-bit encoding that isn't being used here. All characters here are Unicode characters, even if some also exist in various 8-bit code pages. As I explained in my answer, which characters can be used is a matter of which ones were tagged with either `is_alphabetic` or `numeric_type=decimal`.

Comment: I've seen stored procs that were full of poo but never named it!